# Count the number of objects created statically and dynamically in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I have written below program to count the number of static and dynamically created object of the class.

```
#include <iostream>
class Test 
{
   public:
    Test()
    {
      stackCount++;
    }
    
    void* operator new(size_t objSize)
    {
       void* ptr = malloc(objSize);
       heapCount++;
       return ptr;
    }
    
    static void Display()
    {
      std::cout << "stack object count : " << stackCount - heapCount << ", Heap object Count :" <<  
      heapCount << std::endl;
    }
    
   private:
    static int stackCount;
    static int heapCount;
};
    
int Test::stackCount = 0;
int Test::heapCount = 0;
     
int main() 
{
    Test obj1;
    Test obj2;
    Test obj3;
       
    Test *ptr = new Test();
        
    Test::Display();
        
    return 0;
}
```

Program output : stack object count : 3, Heap object Count :1

is there any better way to maintain the count of static and dynamic object.?

Comment: You are actually separating dynamically-allocated full objects from anything else, be it static, automatic, or member (of a class, including lambdas, union, or array).

Comment: I don't see where your code statically allocates anything.

Comment: “is there any better way to maintain the count of static and dynamic object.?” It is literally impossible to do that. Your code does not do that; instead it is relying on undefined behaviour. In your custom `new`, you allocate the memory for the object… *but never call the object’s constructor*. If you did that, you would see your counts don’t work. Why do you want to count heap versus “stack” objects anyway? What’s the point?

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` is used but never defined.  You probably want `std::malloc`, from the `<cstdlib>` header.

Prefer pre-increment (`++i`) to post-increment, if you're not using the result.  For simple arithmetic types, decent compilers will optimise away the copy, but that's not possibly for more complex class types, so cultivate a good habit that can save some performance one day.

On the subject of small performance wins, don't use `std::endl` when there isn't a need to flush the stream (and prefer a separate `std::flush` even then, to keep the intention clear).

I recommend changing how you break long `<<` lines, to make it clearer what's a continuation line even when you can't see the whole line:

```
      std::cout << "stack object count : " << stackCount - heapCount
                << ", Heap object Count :" << heapCount << '\n';
```

See how the indentation and use of `<<` at the start help show that this is a single (logical) line?

You have a memory leak, because you never `delete ptr`.  However, we need to implement a matching `operator delete()` for that to work properly.

Comment: `malloc()` shouldn't be used at all. `operator new()` can simply call `new char[objSize]`.

Comment: If you use `new`, you need to take alignment into account. `malloc()` allocates at maximum alignment, so it’s not a problem there.